# Sci-fi with space-mining scientists, personal internet - book identification help, please

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, space-colonization

About a year ago, my kindle was stolen and I'm really more upset that I can't track down the name of the book I had just sampled and was planning to purchase. I've since replaced the kindle, but I really want to find out what that book was.

If memory serves, it opened with a team of scientists wearing/piloting some sort of robotic mining suits looking for minerals underground on another planet & the lead character was a female scientist. The only other things I recall were that they were actually camped out on a jungle-type planet and that everyone had sort of a personal internet which they could use both to network with others, but also in a information concierge not unlike tony Stark's "Jarvis," but with less personality. I believe the sample ended with some sort of love-scene in a tent. It was really interesting and I recall it being well written - I'd love to read the rest.

I know it's a just a shot in the dark, but if you have any ideas of what this may be, I'd be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You might be able to [lookup the samples you downloaded under "Manage Your Content and Devices"](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201612700) even though you lost the Kindle.